# Healthy smoothie vs multivitamin

Tags: nutrition, vitamins

Seems like one of the benefits of blending things like onions, carrots, cucumbers, etc. all into a super "healthy" smoothie is that the smoothie would contain a tremendous amount of vitamins and minerals. Would it be equally healthy to just have a multi vitamin pill?

Comment: Bioavailability from a multi-vit is actually higher than from food. If you take a pill with a 90mg vit-c, you will absorb more of that vitamin c than if you take it in orange smoothie equivalence. This is not to say that the multi-vit is healthier. Its only better for getting closer to that intake level that you need, with minimal effort. That's a high dose in a short period of time, bringing the questions- will your body actually use that sudden supply & is that sudden supply not toxic to e.g. the liver. Oranges would provide other benefits like fibre, extended release of that vit-c, etc

Answer (score 1):

In short, No. There is something known as bio-availability which in essence means how much of a substance is ACTUALLY absorbed. So just because a mulit-vitamin has all these good things in them doesn't mean it will all be utilised as well as the same vitamin would be in the fruit/vegetable.

To give a somewhat related example (but not perfect) of bio-availability;

"Studies have found that excessive amounts of sugar, or glucose, in the body can inhibit the absorption of Vitamin C. In the 1970s, researchers established that sugar and Vitamin C have a similar structure and enter cells using the same pathway, the GLUT receptors."

https://blog.livonlabs.com/vitamins-and-nutrients/sugar-vitamin-c-intake/

Side note: I highly recommend against putting an onion in a smoothie.

Side note 2: I'm not saying multi-vitamins/supplements aren't helpful.

Comment: Although, on the flip side, bioavailability applies for smoothies as well, just like any food. Just because pumpkin seeds have ruined of protein doesn't mean you can digest it. And one of the reasons the raw food diet is so popular for weight loss is that a lot of the food value of what you consume is lost because it's not cooked.